# sqli sum of a column codes not working

Tags: mysqli, sum

I am trying to sum of a column of database table by the following cods, but it's not working:

```
$sqli = "SELECT sum(total_salary) AS totSalary FROM allsalary WHERE month_session = '$month_name' and org_session = '$org_name' and desig_session = '$desig_name' ORDER BY ID ASC ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqli);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$totl = $stmt->fetch();
$total_salary = $totl['totSalary'];
echo $total_salary;
```

But I could fetch the table correctly.

Now I want to sum the column named 'total_salary', I need a suggestion.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing two essential functions here, bind_param() and bind_result()

```
$sql = "SELECT sum(total_salary) FROM allsalary WHERE month_session = ? 
        and org_session = ? and desig_session = ? ORDER BY ID ASC";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$sttmt->bind_paran("sss",$month_name,$org_name,$desig_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($total_salary);
$stmt->fetch();

echo $total_salary;
```